# Rellenar Matriz dinámica con ascii C++

Tags: c++, ascii

estoy haciendo un tablero de juego usando matrices, busco llenarlo con el 219 del codigo ASCII pero me sale el error **invalid conversion form 'const char*' to 'char'** en la linea `*(*(PunteroTableroJugador + i)+j) = "\219";`, el `**PunteroTableroJugador` esta declarado como una variable global char, ¿Cuál es el problema?

```
void HacerTableros(){ 

PunteroTableroJugador = new char*[Numero];          
for(int i = 0; i < Numero; i++){
    PunteroTableroJugador[i] = new char[Numero];        
}                                                                           
for (int i = 0; i < Numero; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < Numero; j++){ 
     *(*(PunteroTableroJugador + i)+j) = "\219";         
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Intenta usar comillas simples

Comment: En c++ los char son en realidad enteros de un solo byte, te recomiendo que uses el tipo de datos `unsigned char` y al asignar no uses comillas, eso deberia funcionar, asi `*(*(PunteroTableroJugador + i)+j) = 219`

Comment: Sale otro error, **[Warning] overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

un char es un byte, que se puede representar con valores del codigo ASCII, asi que coloca el 219 como un valor, no en comillas;

la asignación:

```
 *(*(PunteroTableroJugador + i)+j) = "\219";
```

debes cambiarla a por

```
PunteroTableroJugador[i][j] = 219;
```